# VSCode (JDWP) doesn't show local variables when reloaded an Quarkus application

Tags: java, quarkus

## Preparation

Create [Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/) Applicatoin.

```
mvn io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:0.11.0:create \
    -DprojectGroupId=org.acme \
    -DprojectArtifactId=application-configuration \
    -DclassName="org.acme.config.GreetingResource" \
    -Dpath="/greeting"
```

2. Startup Appplication.

```
mvn clean compile quarkus:dev -Dmaven.compiler.debug=true  -Dmaven.compiler.optimize=false
```

3. VSCode start Debugging.

launch.json

```
        {
            "type": "java",
            "name": "Debug (Attach)",
            "request": "attach",
            "hostName": "localhost",
            "port": 5005
        }
```

## What happened

Immediately after startup, local variables are visible.
If the source code is rewritten and reload is executed, local variables will not be visible.

I think `-Dmaven.compiler.debug=true  -Dmaven.compiler.optimize=false` is not used ,when  reload app.

Is there any way to solve it?

## Additional information #1

Screenshot is here.
https://qiita.com/h-r-k-matsumoto/private/21d383ce4db99fc238d2

Comment: Very interesting! I am looking into it

Comment: I have opened a PR to fix this: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/1462

Comment: It's amazing! Thank you very much!

Comment: I merged PR in my local environment. I watched local variables as expected.
Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear :). It's now in master as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue will be fixed in 0.12.0.

https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/1462

refer [#comment97026140_55142212](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55142212/vscode-jdwp-doesnt-show-local-variables-when-reloaded-an-quarkus-application#comment97026140_55142212)

Comment: It would be great if you accepted your answer so future users can see that it's been resolved :)

Comment: No problem at all :)